# How to change font weight of memoir titles?

Tags: memoir

How can I change the font weight (a la textmd, textbf, ...) of chapter and section titles in memoir? Below is my MWE. I tried inserting `textbf` etc into the renewcommands but nothing was working for me

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\centering\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\centering\HUGE}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The Beginning}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding `\bfseries` to the `\renewcommand`:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\centering\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\centering\HUGE}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{The Beginning}
\end{document}
```

You can use the weights: `\mdseries` and `\bfseries`

the shapes: `\upshape`, `\itshape`, `\scshape` and `\slshape`

and the families: `\rmfamily`, `\sffamily` and `\ttfamily`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great with the default font but I'm having trouble applying it to Montserrat Thin. I'm sure I'm doing something silly. I posted a follow-up question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686102/how-to-apply-bfseries-to-montserrat-thin-font).