# How to apply bfseries to Montserrat Thin font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, memoir, bold

I have the Montserrat Thin font installed from Google but can't get it to apply the bold style. E.g., my MWE tries to have a bold title using `bfseries` and bold text using `textbf` but neither works? I just get the message `Font shape TU/MontserratThin(0)/b/n undefinedundefined (Font) using TU/MontserratThin(0)/m/n` instead`. I checked and the installed font has "bold" and several other weights.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{Montserrat Thin}

\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\centering\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\centering\titlefont\HUGE\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{The Beginning}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*EDIT*: Here's the screen shot of font in Font Book:

[image]

Comment: You're just using `Montserrat Thin`, which may not have a **bold** series. Did you [download the whole Montserrat font family](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat)?

Comment: `\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{Montserrat}`.

Comment: @Werner I added a screen shot of the Montserrat Thin in Font Book. It has Bold.

Comment: @Clara, I don't have `Montserrat` installed. I have `Montserrat Thin` from fonts.google.com

Comment: @buttonsrtoys Montserrat has been pre installed in MacTeX.

Comment: @Clara, I deleted the installed Montserrat because it didn't have italic. Montserrat Thin has italic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Montserrat font family features nine [9!] font weights, ordered from lightest to heaviest: `Thin`, `ExtraLight`, `Light`, `Regular`, `Medium`, `SemiBold`, `Bold`, `ExtraBold`, and `Black`.

A rule of thumb says that a bold counterpart to a basic font weight should be 2 or 3 steps heavier than the basic weight. (Do note, for instance, that in the Montserrat font family the weight that's three steps up from `Regular` is `Bold`.) For the Montserrat font family, then, either `Light` or `Regular` would appear to be good candidates to act as a suitable bold font weight to go with `Thin`. For instance,

```
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{Montserrat Thin}[BoldFont={Montserrat Regular}]
```

Of course, you are entirely free to go up four or more steps, e.g., to  `Medium` or evenn `SemiBold`, if that's what you prefer.

---

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{Montserrat Thin}[%
      BoldFont      = {Montserrat Regular},
      ItalicFont    = {Montserrat Thin Italic},
      BoldItalicFont= {Montserrat Italic}]

\begin{document}
\titlefont\Huge
The Beginning 

\textbf{The Beginning}

\itshape
The Beginning 

\textbf{The Beginning}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This wasn't the answer I was looking for but has such great info I marked it as the answer. The issue was, as shown in my OP, the Google Montserrat font installs as "Montserrat Thin" instead of "Montserrat" so the above didn't work. I contacted Google and they agreed it was a bug and are looking into it. In the mean time I found a bug-free version of Montserrat at https://www.cdnfonts.com/montserrat.font that worked great with this solution.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys - My answer may have been affected by my system being MacOS 13.3.1 "Ventura", which comes with 9 weights and two shapes (upright and italic) for Montserrat, for a total of 18 font files.

Comment: I'm on 13.3.1 too. I had removed the Montserrat font and installed the Google version, which is when things started going sideways.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys - Thanks for this additional information. It might have been helpful to mention up front that you were operating with a nonstandard font setup.

Comment: Sorry about that @Mico. I thought I did when I described that I was using the Montserrat Thin font from Google.